# Post tweet using twiterouath library

Tags: php, codeigniter, twitter

i am tring post tweet using twitteroauth library. This is my code

```
    require("application/libraries/twitteroauth.php");
    $twitteroauth = new TwitterOAuth(TW_KEY, TW_SECRET);
    $request_token = $twitteroauth->getRequestToken();
    print_r($request_token);

    $tweet = new TwitterOAuth(TW_KEY, TW_SECRET, $request_token['oauth_token'], $request_token['oauth_token_secret']);
    // the message
    $message = "This is an example twitter post using PHP";
    // send to twitter
    $msg = $tweet->post('statuses/update', array('status' => $message));
    print_r($msg); die;
```

But every time i got follwing error message

```
stdClass Object(
[errors] => Array(
        [0] => stdClass Object
            (
                [message] => Invalid or expired token
                [code] => 89
            )

    )
```

Request token is generated successfully.how i solve my problem. please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you login inside your Developer Twitter API Panel , you will be provided with 4 parameters.. i.e. The consumer key, consumer secret, oAuth Token and oAuth Secret. Just copy it from the panel and paste it on your PHP code like this...

```
    $consumerKey    = 'LFrw******gQtXopxeQ';
    $consumerSecret = '2rM0R*********aj8GXik4w';
    $oAuthToken     = '1127*********wcjnl9dNsVtTSb';
    $oAuthSecret    = '4fM**********TB52rwpnP6kyh';
```

after that just give a call...

```
    require_once('twitteroauth.php');
    $tweet = new TwitterOAuth($consumerKey, $consumerSecret, $oAuthToken, $oAuthSecret);
    $tweet->get('account/verify_credentials');
    $message = "This is the first tweet from Shankar ;)"; // I have added a message here

    $tweet->post('statuses/update', array('status' => $message)); // Will do.. !
```

Comment: i do same but now tweet is posted on my profile not the profile of login users

Comment: Ofcourse that is what you requested on your code right ? If you want to post on others profile. Look for the API link here https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/post/direct_messages/new

Answer (score 0):

The default Twitter App permission set only to read only. You need to update the twitter app permission to Read and Write.

Comment: That would have produced different status error not `Invalid or expired token` message.

Comment: it is my request uri  https://api.twitter.com/1/ and request method is get . is it effect?